# Responsive CSS submenu

Tags: css, responsive

I've made this navigation with CSS and now I'm trying to make it responsive using media queries, but I can't get the submenus to show properly. In responsive mode, I'd like to display the full menu with all links neatly underneath each other in one box. Would really appreciate some help!

https://jsfiddle.net/4L8ghza0/1/

HTML:

```
<header>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#" ID="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Start</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Submenu1 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu2 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link6</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>                   
            </ul>
            </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
top: 0px;
background-color: #EFE7D2;
position: fixed !important;
width: 100%;
height: 125px;
z-index: 10;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.nav {
float: right;
padding: 40px 80px 0 0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 95%;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}

ul li a {
padding: 8px 10px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
}

ul li:hover{
background: #CCB18E;
}

.nav .arrow {
font-size: 70%;
line-height: 0%;
}

ul li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 210%;
padding: 0;
}

ul li ul li {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
background: #CCB18E;
padding: 0px 10px;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}

ul li ul li:hover  {
display: block;
background: #DAC7AD;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0px 10px;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
visibility:visible;
}

ul ul li:hover li{
display:block;
}

.current {
background:#CCB18E;
color: #000000;
}

#menu-icon {
display: hidden;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-4/128/menu-2-512.png) center;
}

a:hover#menu-icon {
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px){
#menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li ul li a {
    display: block; 
}
ul, ul:active {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #EFE7D2;
    right: 100px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px #5F7B65 solid;
}
.nav:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
ul li:hover ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@JD26 I find it easier using `flex-box`. You can set `.nav {display: flex; flex-direction:column;}` in your media query. This should get you started. Or with block display: `.nav {display: block}`.

Comment: Thank you! But this didn't do anything I'm afraid.. :( starting to wonder if it's even possible to display the full menu without a completely new HTML code for the mobile version